# Will I Need a Transit visa or ESTA for the US as a Canadian?

Tags: air-travel, usa, germany, esta

I'm a Canadian traveling from Toronto To Warsaw and I have connecting flights in New Jersey and Frankfurt.
Will I need an ESTA or a Transit Visa?

Comment: You're on a Canadian passport, I assume?

Comment: Yes, this is my first flight ever so I'm not sure.

Comment: No, you will not. Canadian citizens don't need a visa for short trips to the USA. Only if a Canadian citizen has "any sort of criminal record, including drunk driving," he or she might be required to get a visa. http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/information-for-canadians/canadians-requiring-visas.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good news - as a Canadian citizen, you're a member of one of the few groups that don't need visas for the US.

From the [Canadian Embassy website](http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/visas/esta.html):

**Note: ESTA is not required for citizens of Canada.**

On 12 January 2009, the Department of Homeland Security (DHS) introduced ESTA, the Electronic System for Travel Authorization. This online system is part of the Visa Waiver Program (VWP), and all nationals or citizens of VWP countries -- **excluding Canada** -- who plan to travel to the United States for 90 days or less for temporary business or pleasure under the VWP need to receive an electronic travel authorization prior to boarding a U.S.-bound airplane or cruise ship.

So you'll be fine travelling through the US on the way to Germany!  Enjoy your trip.

Comment: No problem.  If you like the answers, please do vote them up/accept them, and if you enjoy the site, stick around, read the [faq], and get involved - you may have questions about Warsaw that people can help with :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, Canada is not a VWP country.

Answer (score 3):

The US government has [a page for Canadian citizens](http://travel.state.gov/visa/temp/without/without_1260.html). It says:

> Citizens of Canada traveling to the United States do not require a nonimmigrant visa

with a few exceptions that probably don't apply to you.