# Do Canadian citizens need to apply for a visa to attend a job interview in the U.S.?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, business-travel

I am a Canadian citizen and I have been asked to attend an interview in the U.S. with one of the big tech companies. I have been only a Canadian citizen for a short time now, and I am not sure whether I need to apply for a some sort of business visa to enter the states for interview purposes. Do I need any kind of visa?

In either case (visa needed or not needed) do I need to present the U.S. border control any documents regarding my interview?

Can anyone please share their experiences? Thanks!

Comment: Relevant earlier question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22560/travelling-to-the-us-on-the-visa-waiver-program-vwp-to-attend-a-job-interview (it's not really the same situation as Canadian citizens [do not even need an ESTA](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16006/will-i-need-a-transit-visa-or-esta-for-the-us-as-a-canadian) but it suggests you should be OK). Hopefully someone else will be able to confirm that more authoritatively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are traveling with a **Canadian passport**.  From the [State Department](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html):

> Citizens of Canada and Bermuda do not require visas to enter the United States, for visit, tourism and temporary business travel purposes. For more information see [U.S. Embassy Ottawa website](http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/information-for-canadians.html), U.S. Consulate Hamilton website and [CBP website](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1094)..
>
> Additional resources for Canadian visitors to the United States can be found on the U.S. Embassy and Consulate websites in Canada.

If the CBP officer asks for the purpose of the visit you can tell him that you're meeting with a prospective employer.